# CSS/ Flexbox: Same width as largest element, like columns

Tags: css, flexbox

I've built a list component for my app, I can't use tables because of the style.

I want to have the elements inside of the "rows" to have the same width from top to bottom, like columns. The code looks similar to this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class"element>iPhone </div>
  <div class"element>Buy an iPhone now!</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class"element>Airport Express </div>
  <div class"element>Buy an Airport Express now!</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class"element>iPad </div>
  <div class"element>Buy an iPad now!</div>
</div>
```

This is what it currently looks like:

[image: What it looks like]

And this is, what I want:

[image: What it should look like]

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use CSS tables:

- Separation between rows with `border-spacing`
- Borders in cells. You can use `border-radius` to round them.
- Pseudo-element displayed as cell to fill available space at the right
- `white-space: nowrap` to prevent cells from shrinking due to the pseudo-element.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 0 10px;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.row::after {
  content: '';
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px #6AACC9;
  border-style: solid none;
}
.element {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #6AACC9;
  border-right-color: #adadad;
  border-left-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.element:first-child {
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="element">iPhone </div>
    <div class="element">Buy an iPhone now!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="element">Airport Express </div>
    <div class="element">Buy an Airport Express now!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="element">iPad </div>
    <div class="element">Buy an iPad now!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that with flexbox. Dimensions cannot be equallised between elements that do not share a parent.

But you can with **CSS Tables**

```css
.row {

  display: table-row;

}

.element {

  display: table-cell;

  border: 1px solid grey;

  padding: 8px;

}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="element">iPhone</div>
  <div class="element">Buy an iPhone now!</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="element">Airport Express</div>
  <div class="element">Buy an Airport Express now!</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="element">iPad</div>
  <div class="element">Buy an iPad now!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to have the row `width: 100%` and the elements be on the left side, like the image?